# Combining two tables to a single entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have this old system of two related tables, orders and orderextras. The order-table has Id as its primary key, customer name as a scalar property and an orderextra_Id as a foreign key. The orderextra has only two properties, Id as its primary key and a varchar called extrainfo.

Now I've just began reading EF 4.0 Recipes and in quite the beginning it demonstrated combining two tables into a single entity (so basically, I'd want the extrainfo to appear on the order-entity, and not have the orderextra as an entity at all). However, in the example, both tables shared the same PK. Is it possible to do this when they have separate PKs and one of the tables references the other one?

Comment: If you don't need to write to this combined entity and your back-end is SQL, you could just create a view in SQL and add the view to your entities.

Comment: Yeah that'd work if I didn't need to write back, but I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { /* order columns */ });
        m.ToTable("order");
    })
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { /* orderextra columns */ });
        m.ToTable("orderextra");
    });
```

Comment: Oh I guess I should've been more specific. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this from the designer. I don't even know what this modelbuilder you speak of is :) Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @bobblez The `modelBuilder` is part of the code-first fluent api. So this doesn't help you if you use the designer.

Comment: @bobblez I don't know the names of all the files off the top of my head, but in my experience the GUI is just abstracting this file david is talking about modifying. I haven't messed with it much but have had to for various reasons (for some reason one of my translate functions randomly acquired a second required param after a db modification). I wouldn't stray from it, you'll sure have to touch it at some point and it's fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer, on one of the entities, add the columns you want from the two tables and go to the Mapping Details window.

From there, you should see Tables -> "Maps to XXX table".  Underneath that, you can add another table and map columns that way so you have more than one table, to the properties you want.

Comment: Yeah this is what I tried, but when I tried to iterate over the context.Orders -collection, I always got an Entity<something>Exception (where <something> changed depending on what I tried). The problem seemed to relate to the Id fields. Specifically, what to map to the Id of the orderextra-table. EF seems to complain about having to map all key properties no matter what I try to map to it.